# javafx how to add several elements in one window?

Tags: javafx

I'm using eclipse with scene builder.
I have build a new fxml document with:
- 2 labels
- one table view
[image: element]

I want to add several of this element into other window (i.e. add several of this element into tilePane).

How can I do it ?
When I'm trying to do this:

```
Pane pane1 = (Pane)loader.load();
Pane pane2 = (Pane)loader.load();            
tilePaneRootLayout.getChildren().add(pane1);
tilePaneRootLayout.getChildren().add(pane2);
```

I'm getting empty window.
1. why this happen ?
2. how can I solve it ?
Thanks

Comment: Try to create a new `loader` for each new `Pane`

Comment: It work, Thanks.
Is there any bettet design to do what I want ?

Comment: Since, you are using `FXML`, I can't think of any other approach

Answer (score 1):

Create a new `loader` for each new `Pane`